# How To Create a new DF Column By checking a lookup table and inserting the appropriate value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, the first is a cartesian joined table which has the below structure:

| track_x | Energy_x | Camelot_x | BPM_x | join | track_y | Energy_y | Camelot_y | BPM_y | Energy_Distance | BPM Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Buju Banton - Blessed | 5 | 10A | 75 | 1 | Gyptian - Hold You - Hold Yuh | 6 | 4B | 67 | 1 | 8 |

where it has around 10k rows with every track referencing every other track.

I then have a second table which i am using to store the distances between camelot_x & camelot_y which has the columns and indexes as the 10A, 4B value for example and then the value as an integer.

|  | 1A | 1B | 2A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1B | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2A | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I am struggling however to retrieve this corresponding value.

I have used code:

```
def harmonic_distance_lookup(x, y):
    value = distance_df.lookup(x, y)
    return value


ct_df["Harmonic Distance"] = ct_df.apply(harmonic_distance_lookup(ct_df["Camelot_x"], ct_df["Camelot_y"]), axis=1)
```

However this just spins forever and doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Is there a better method of doing this? I want to check the distance between camelot_x & camelot_y for every row and append it to a new column

Expected output:
|track_x|Energy_x|Camelot_x|BPM_x|join|track_y|Energy_y|Camelot_y|BPM_y|Energy_Distance|BPM Distance| Harmonic Distance|
|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|
|Buju Banton - Blessed|5|10A|75|1|Gyptian - Hold You - Hold Yuh|6|4B|67|1|8|6|

Working Answer:

```
def harmonic_distance_lookup(x, y):
    value = distance_df.at[x, y]
    return value


ct_df["Harmonic Distance"] = ct_df.apply(lambda x: harmonic_distance_lookup(x["Camelot_x"], x["Camelot_y"]), axis=1)
ct_df
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ct_df.apply(lambda x: harmonic_distance_lookup(x["Camelot_x"], x["Camelot_y"]), axis=1)
```

Also `df.lookup` is deprecated in `1.2.0`.  You might want to look at `df.at`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. I changed the function to the below:
```
def harmonic_distance_lookup(x, y):
    value = distance_df.at[x, y]
    return value


ct_df["Harmonic Distance"] = ct_df.apply(lambda x: harmonic_distance_lookup(x["Camelot_x"], x["Camelot_y"]), axis=1)
ct_df
```